# How can I use multiple combinations of font styles in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, fonts

If I want to set my Font I can use

```
new Font=("Times New Roman", 12, Drawing.FontStyle.Bold)
```

Instead of Bold, I can use Italic, Regular or Underline.

But I want to make use of Bold and Italic at the same time.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [`FontStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.fontstyle.aspx) enumeration is a flags enumeration, so you can combine values (using the `Or` operator in VB.NET, `|` in c#):

```
new Font("Times New Roman", 12, Drawing.FontStyle.Bold Or Drawing.FontStyle.Italic)
```

Comment: Thanks dear. I tired using and. Thanks indeed.

Comment: PowerShell was a little balky about this--you can't just take the result of the bitwise or operation and use it as an argument, you have to cast it back to a **[System.Drawing.FontStyle]**. For posterity, here's the syntax that worked for me: `$Label.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',8.25,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]([System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold -bor [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Underline))`.