# vb net Remove partial font style in rich text box

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox, rtf, text-styling

I have a rich text box that I want to be able to style like WORD etc with BOLD, ITALIC, UNDERLINE and any combination of them.
I can add and remove say BOLD styling with the code below and I can also add multiple stylings but if I have multiple stylings set and try to remove one nothing happens.

Style Change Code:

```
Private Sub Underline_Text(rtBox As RichTextBox)
    Dim newStyle As FontStyle
    If rtBox.SelectionFont.Style = FontStyle.Underline Then
        newStyle = rtBox.SelectionFont.Style And Not FontStyle.Underline
    Else
        newStyle = rtBox.SelectionFont.Style Or FontStyle.Underline
    End If
    Dim newFont As New Font(rtBox.SelectionFont.Name, rtBox.SelectionFont.Size, newStyle)
    rtBox.SelectionFont = newFont
End Sub
```

Full Code:

```
Private Sub rtbDesc_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles rtbDesc.KeyDown
    If e.Control AndAlso Not e.Alt AndAlso Not e.Shift Then
        Select Case e.KeyCode.ToString
            Case "B"
                Bold_Text(DirectCast(sender, RichTextBox))
                e.SuppressKeyPress = True
            Case "I"
                Italics_Text(DirectCast(sender, RichTextBox))
                e.SuppressKeyPress = True
            Case "U"
                Underline_Text(DirectCast(sender, RichTextBox))
                e.SuppressKeyPress = True
            Case "R"
                Reset_Text(DirectCast(sender, RichTextBox))
                e.SuppressKeyPress = True
            Case "K"
                Strikeout_Text(DirectCast(sender, RichTextBox))
                e.SuppressKeyPress = True
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub Bold_Text(rtBox As RichTextBox)
    Dim newStyle As FontStyle
    If rtBox.SelectionFont.Style = FontStyle.Bold Then
        newStyle = rtBox.SelectionFont.Style And Not FontStyle.Bold
    Else
        newStyle = rtBox.SelectionFont.Style Or FontStyle.Bold
    End If
    Dim newFont As New Font(rtBox.SelectionFont.Name, rtBox.SelectionFont.Size, newStyle)
    rtBox.SelectionFont = newFont
End Sub
Private Sub Italics_Text(rtBox As RichTextBox)
    Dim newStyle As FontStyle
    If rtBox.SelectionFont.Style = FontStyle.Italic Then
        newStyle = rtBox.SelectionFont.Style And Not FontStyle.Italic
    Else
        newStyle = rtBox.SelectionFont.Style Or FontStyle.Italic
    End If
    Dim newFont As New Font(rtBox.SelectionFont.Name, rtBox.SelectionFont.Size, newStyle)
    rtBox.SelectionFont = newFont
End Sub
Private Sub Underline_Text(rtBox As RichTextBox)
    Dim newStyle As FontStyle
    If rtBox.SelectionFont.Style = FontStyle.Underline Then
        newStyle = rtBox.SelectionFont.Style And Not FontStyle.Underline
    Else
        newStyle = rtBox.SelectionFont.Style Or FontStyle.Underline
    End If
    Dim newFont As New Font(rtBox.SelectionFont.Name, rtBox.SelectionFont.Size, newStyle)
    rtBox.SelectionFont = newFont
End Sub
Private Sub Reset_Text(rtBox As RichTextBox)
    Dim newFont As New Font(rtBox.SelectionFont.Name, rtBox.SelectionFont.Size, FontStyle.Regular)
    rtBox.SelectionFont = newFont
End Sub
Private Sub Strikeout_Text(rtBox As RichTextBox)
    Dim newStyle As FontStyle
    If rtBox.SelectionFont.Style = FontStyle.Strikeout Then
        newStyle = rtBox.SelectionFont.Style And Not FontStyle.Strikeout
    Else
        newStyle = rtBox.SelectionFont.Style Or FontStyle.Strikeout
    End If
    Dim newFont As New Font(rtBox.SelectionFont.Name, rtBox.SelectionFont.Size, newStyle)
    rtBox.SelectionFont = newFont
End Sub
```

As always, your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Man this was a tricky one.

I copied your code and put a breakpoint in your `Bold_Text` method. What I found is your If statement is not checking for the `Bold and Underline` condition. Here's the code I meant:

```
If rtBox.SelectionFont.Style = FontStyle.Underline Then
```

When I added the breakpoint, when trying to remove the bold, it skipped this condition and went to the `Else` clause because you only check to see if it is bold, not bold **and** underlined. Add a MessageBox before the If statement to see that it is detecting both Bold and Underline styles applied like this:

```
MessageBox.Show(rtBox.SelectionFont.Style.ToString)
```

That shows that `rtBox.SelectionFont.Style` is set to "Bold, Underline".

To fix it, I used this code:

```
If (rtBox.SelectionFont.Style = FontStyle.Bold) OrElse (rtBox.SelectionFont.Style = (FontStyle.Bold Or FontStyle.Underline)) Then
```

See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186810/how-can-i-use-multiple-combinations-of-font-styles-in-vb-net) for a little more of an explanation.

> The FontStyle enumeration is a flags enumeration, so you can combine values (using the Or operator in VB.NET...

Comment: That makes sense. I was wondering if it wasn't checking for both. seems very verbose to have to check for each situation tho... Isn't there a CONTAINS method or something similar for font style? In the end, all I want to do is toggle that specific style on/off without effecting any other style that might be applied to the same text.

Comment: I agree, it is verbose. Unfortunately it was the only way I could get it to work. You could probably just make one method that checks for all permutations of FontStyles and just call that in each If statement.

Comment: Also, if this answered your question, please make sure to mark it as the answer/upvote as you feel appropriate. Thanks.

Comment: I was just holding out for the super simplified version haha. Marked as Answered. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This was the way I ultimately resolved my issue FWIW.
Instead of trying all combinations of styles I used Sylverac's trick of sending the style to a string and simply checking for the keyword of the style in question in that returned string etc.

Code:

```
Private Sub Bold_Text(rtBox As RichTextBox)
    Dim newStyle As FontStyle
    If InStr(rtBox.SelectionFont.Style.ToString, "Bold") Then 'Changed this line to search the string
        newStyle = rtBox.SelectionFont.Style And Not FontStyle.Bold
    Else
        newStyle = rtBox.SelectionFont.Style Or FontStyle.Bold
    End If
    Dim newFont As New Font(rtBox.SelectionFont.Name, rtBox.SelectionFont.Size, newStyle)
    rtBox.SelectionFont = newFont
End Sub
```

Comment: Well glad I could help. I didn't even think of doing it that way, nice elegant solution.